# Show a text overlay on top of applications, e.g. for screencast or presentation

Tags: window

I am working on a screencast. Now I am wondering if there is an easy way to place a text box, possibly with transparent background and big font, on top of other windows.

Obviously I could edit the video after the fact. But in this question I am asking for something that would happen live, during the shoot. Another use case would be a presentation, where things need to happen live.

Behavior / controls:

- The text would be pre-written, or it could be written spontaneously.
- It has to be easy to make the box show up and disappear.

Appearance:

- The text box has to be borderless, no window decorations.
- It would typically appear in the middle of the screen, or anywhere I place it.
- The background should be transparent, or possibly mono-colored.
- The appearance could be like the typical text-box overlays in Youtube videos, or something else
- The font should be quite big.

Use case (as already said):

- Screencasts
- Presentations. E.g. someone asks a question, the presenter responds with a book name, author name, or url, which they want to spell out in a way that is easy to read.

This seems technically not too complicated. But I have not found anything like this so far.